# Regular expression to validate 2 character hex string

Tags: regex

I have a source of data that was converted from an oracle database and loaded into a hadoop storage point. One of the columns was a BLOB and therefore had lots of control characters and unreadable/undetectable ascii characters outside of the available codeset.  I am using Impala to write regex replace function to parse some of the unicode characters that the regex library *cannot* understand.  I would like to remove the offending 2 character hex codes BEFORE I use the unhex query function so that I can do the rest of the regex parsing with a "clean" string.

Here's the code I've used so far, which doesn't quite work:

```
'[2-7]{1}([A-Fa-f]|[0-9]{1})'
```

I've determined that I only need to capture `\u0020-\u007f` *- or represented in the two bit hex -* **`20-7f`**

If my string looks like this:

```
010A000000153020405C00000000143020405CBC000000F53320405C4C010000E12F204058540100002D01
```

I would like to be able to capture `2` characters at a time (e.g. `01,0A,00`) evaluate whether or not that fits the acceptable range of `2 byte` hex I mentioned above and return only what is acceptable.

The correct output should be:

```
30 20 40 5C 30 20 40 5C 33 20 40 5C 4C 2F 20 40 58 and 54
```

However, my expression finds the first acceptable number in my first range (5) and starts the capture from there which returns the position or indexing wrong for the rest of the string... and this is the return from my expression -

```
010A0000001**53**0**20****40****5C**000000001**43**0**20****40****5C**BC000000F**53****32**0**40****5C****4C**010000E1**2F****20****40****58****54**010000**2D**01
```

I just don't know how to evaluate only two characters at a time in a mixed-length string.  And, if they don't fit the expression, iterate to the next two characters. But only in two character increments.

My example: https://regex101.com/r/BZL7t0/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a Positieve Lookbehind to it. Which starts at the beginning of the string and then matches 2 characters at the time. This ensures that the group you're matching always has groups of 2 characters before it.

Positieve Lookbehind:

```
(?<=^(..)*)
```

Updated regex:

```
(?<=^(..)*)([2-7]{1}[A-Fa-f0-9]{1})
```

Preview:
[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BZL7t0/3)

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was needing!! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Could you accept the answer and close the question? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the positive look behind? I am using google RE2 which doesn't support lookbehind @Jeroen Groenveld